# How to express a foldl-based code with foldr?

Tags: haskell, fold

I am attempting to convert a list of integers into a single integer using the `foldr` function. I have seen implementations that use the `foldl` function but am trying to figure out how to do the same thing using `foldr`.

The output should look something like:

```
list2int [0,1,2,3,0,4,5]
>123045
```

My code:

```
list2int :: [Int] -> Int
list2int = foldr (\x acc -> acc*10 + x) 0
```

However, when I run the code above using the same input, it returns 5403210. .

Comment: Please elaborate why you prefer `foldr` over `foldl`?

Answer (score 9):

I don't really recommend this, but it exists.

```
ghci> foldr (\x k acc -> k $! (10 * acc + x)) id [0,1,2,3,0,4,5] 0
123045
```

The reason I don't recommend it is that it's roughly the same thing as inlining the definition of [`foldl'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:foldl-39-), but harder to read.

And this is really a problem that should use `foldl'` to solve. It associates the operation the correct direction and has the correct strictness. Problems like this are the whole reason it exists.

Answer (score 5):

Let's run through what happens with your function when you fold over `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5]`:

```
foldr (\x acc -> acc*10 + x) 0 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5]
foldr (\x acc -> acc*10 + x) 5 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
foldr (\x acc -> acc*10 + x) 50 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
foldr (\x acc -> acc*10 + x) 504 [0, 1, 2, 3]
foldr (\x acc -> acc*10 + x) 5043 [0, 1, 2]
foldr (\x acc -> acc*10 + x) 50432 [0, 1]
foldr (\x acc -> acc*10 + x) 504321 [0]
foldr (\x acc -> acc*10 + x) 5043210 []
5043210
```

But what if we provide `foldr` with a tuple, containing our accumulator, and a *base* to multiply each digit by?

Our initial value will be a base of 1 and an accumulator of 0: `(1, 0)`. Each time through, we'll multiply the base by 10.

```
Prelude> foldr (\x (base, acc) -> (base * 10, acc + x * base)) (1, 0) [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5]
(10000000,123045)
Prelude>
```

Now, consider what happens:

```
foldr (\x (base, acc) -> (base * 10, acc + x * base)) (1, 0) [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5]
foldr (\x (base, acc) -> (base * 10, acc + x * base)) (10, 5) [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4]
foldr (\x (base, acc) -> (base * 10, acc + x * base)) (100, 45) [0, 1, 2, 3, 0]
foldr (\x (base, acc) -> (base * 10, acc + x * base)) (1000, 45) [0, 1, 2, 3]
foldr (\x (base, acc) -> (base * 10, acc + x * base)) (10000, 3045) [0, 1, 2]
foldr (\x (base, acc) -> (base * 10, acc + x * base)) (100000, 23045) [0, 1]
foldr (\x (base, acc) -> (base * 10, acc + x * base)) (1000000, 123045) [0]
foldr (\x (base, acc) -> (base * 10, acc + x * base)) (10000000, 123045) []
(10000000, 123045)
```

This basic pattern of using a tuple to pass state through iterations of a fold may be useful to you in the future.

Now we just need to extract the second number in this tuple, and you have the desired result.

It's also possible to pass the base, and multiply the current number by 10 raised to that base, starting with a base power of `0`.

```
Prelude> foldr (\x (basePow, acc) -> (basePow + 1, acc + x * 10 ** basePow)) (0, 0) [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5]
(7.0,123045.0)
Prelude>
```

Credit to Will Ness for pointing out the most elegant solution to this problem with `foldl`. The above demonstration of `foldr` is just one approach to solving this problem. Hopefully viewing multiple approaches to solving the same problem will be instructive.

Comment: this is just _not_ how foldr works, even though these re-writes are extensionally equivalent.

Comment: I agree with @WillNess: the implementation seems to be correct, but the explanation is off. Lists are not symmetrical in Haskell.

Comment: I was not attempting to provide an explanation of how `foldr` _works_ but rather demonstrate stepping through the reduction of the list to an integer in a digestible manner. If you have any specific suggestions on improving the answer, I am open to suggested edits.

Comment: showing the reductions step by step _is_ showing how it "works". as I noticed, your sequences do produce the same results, but in a different way. (and we need to prove it to ourselves that it is indeed equivalent).

Answer (score 2):

Using your code with `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5]` works as

```
foldr (\x acc -> acc*10 + x) 0 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5]
= {- it's easier to see this way: -}
foldr (\x acc -> x + 10*acc) 0 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5]
=
0 + 10*(1 + 10*(2 + 10*(3 + 10*(4 + 10*(0 + 10*(5 + 10*(0)))))))
```

We just [replace each `,`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#As_structural_transformations)  (and the ending bracket) in the list with  `+ 10*(`, put  the `0` in the end, and balance the parens. *That* is what `foldr` is doing.

So this treats the lists as starting with the least significant digit, instead of the most significant, as they actually are.

The correct way to express this is with the left fold,

```
foldl (\acc x -> acc*10 + x) 0 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5]
=
(((((((0)*10 + 0)*10 + 1)*10 + 2)*10 + 3)*10 + 4)*10 + 0)*10 + 5
```

Again, we just replace each `,`  (and the *opening* bracket) in the list with `)*10 +` , put the `0` in the *front*, and balance the parens. And that's what `foldl` is doing.

For reasons of efficiency, as mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69339764/849891) by [Carl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383200/carl), `foldl'` should be used here instead of `foldl` (which is usually the case).

To still be doing this with `foldr`, it must be composed with `reverse`:

```
foldr (\x acc -> acc*10 + x) 0 . reverse $ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5]
```

and when you write out `reverse` as a right fold and compose the two folds into one you'll probably end up with the version shown in Carl's answer. Could be a nice exercise to work through.

Comment: The structural meaning of `foldr` might be easier to understand if you remove the syntactic sugar around lists; then `foldr c n xs` simply converts all `(:)` in `xs` to `c`, and the `[]` in `xs` to `n`.

Comment: @jlwoodwa that's what I was referring to, with "replacing each comma with ...". I realize it is not usually stated that way, but it _is_ equivalent. :) and the list sugar is more economical than all the conses. it's just something that goes in between the data, cons, comma, doesn't _really_ matter. :)